# SQLiteDatabase Object being passed as Null, even when Initialised at Constructor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-manifest

I am having error in this for past couple of days, have tried using breakpoints to figure why is it giving null pointer exception, but i am not able to understand which value is getting stuck. How can i make db be not null, so as to run this code. 
I have an abstract class that calls this method on certain conditional statement. It has to return a long value. Which is to be used for some other method.

This method long save is implemented in another class which returns a value after calling db.insert, but i am getting Null Pointer Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference
```

I have following doubts :

1. Why is this giving error when i am using it in Fragment, but when i am using with Activity it's working fine. What can be the reason.
2. Also How is getWritableDatabase gets called when i pass db as an argument.

   ```
   long save(SQLiteDatabase db) {


           ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
           long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
           cv.put(COL_CREATEDTIME, now);
           cv.put(COL_MODIFIEDTIME, now);
           //cv.putNull(COL_MODIFIEDTIME);
           cv.put(COL_NAME, name==null ? "" : name);
           //if (fromDate != null)
           cv.put(COL_FROMDATE, fromDate==null ? "" :fromDate);
           //if (toDate != null)
           cv.put(COL_TODATE, toDate==null ? "" :toDate);
           //if (rule != null)
           cv.put(COL_RULE, rule==null ? "" :rule);
           //if (interval != null)
           cv.put(COL_INTERVAL, interval==null ? "" :interval);
           cv.put(COL_SOUND, sound ? 1 : 0);
           //if (sound != null)

           //Log.e(TAG, "Error inserting " + now);
           return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, cv);}
   ```

[image: db Usage. Hope this helps to understand the flow of the code]

```
public class DosageDB extends Application {


    public static DBHelper dbHelper;
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public static final String TIME_OPTION = "time_option";
    public static final String DATE_RANGE = "date_range";
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "date_format";
    public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "time_format";
    public static final String VIBRATE_PREF = "vibrate_pref";
    public static final String RINGTONE_PREF = "ringtone_pref";

    public static final String DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-M-d";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,R.xml.settings, false);
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    }
}
```

Stacktrace :

```
09-10 15:05:39.582    2423-2423/healerkart.com.dosage E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: healerkart.com.dosage, PID: 2423
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference
            at healerkart.com.dosage.Delta.Alarm.save(Alarm.java:65)
            at healerkart.com.dosage.Delta.AbstractModel.persist(AbstractModel.java:54)
            at healerkart.com.dosage.Delta.Alarm.persist(Alarm.java:10)
            at healerkart.com.dosage.Alpha.dosageFrag$2.onClick(dosageFrag.java:134)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Where calling `save` method?

Comment: in the Abstract Class

public long persist(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  if (id > 0)
  {
   if (update(db))
    return id;
   else
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
   return (save(db));
  }


 }

Comment: db is null not the instance of ContentValues

Comment: Yeah, db is null. How to make it not null, because i can't understand where to initialise it's value anywhere.

Comment: @dARK-f3n1Xx: means `db` is `null`

Comment: where calling `persist` method?

Comment: It's in the Fragment Class :  alarmId = alarm.persist(db);

Comment: in that fragment class : public SQLiteDatabase db;

Comment: persist is being called in an onClick() does it effects the db?

Comment: Show the code that creates or opens the database `db`.

Comment: @CL. It's in DosageDB 

`dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

Comment: Edit the question to show that code in context.

Comment: `dbHelper = new DBHelper(this); db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` Is this code executing before calling `persist()` ?

Comment: I think yes, because db=DosageDB.db is being called in onCreate method of Fragment, and persist is being called in onClick method of the Fragment

Comment: where is `DosageDB.db` being initialised? like `this.db = db;`

Comment: `public dosageFrag()
    {
        db = DosageDB.db;
    }`

Comment: Should i include db= Dosage.db in the Abstract Class as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DosageDB was extending Application, i forgot to mention the Application name attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml
Thanks anyways.